# Disable the screensaver in Red Hat

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, screensaver

I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux WS release 4 (Nahant Update 2).

Please help to disable the screensaver.

Answer (score 2):

To disable for the current user:

```
gconftool-2 --set -t boolean /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled false
```

To set the system default to disabled:

```
gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults --set -t boolean /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled false
```

To re-enable it you simply change the bool from false to true, like so:

re-enable current user:

```
gconftool-2 --set -t boolean /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled true
```

re-enable default:

```
gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults --set -t boolean /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled true
```

Comment: please provide guidance on how to re-enable it again. it might be useful to the QA or any other reader.

Comment: @Znau good point, edited

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in GUI mode using `screensaver-properties-capplet` command.